# Silverlight Resources Directory

Tags: silverlight

If you have any links to nice animations, effects, basically any Silverlight resources please list them here.

Searching in google frustrates me, but it is probably due to me not knowing Silverlight and it's terminology that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good place to start sampling themes and applications, is here: [Microsoft Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Download Silverlight [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) and look for Themes\Xaml folder. here is an online sample of those [themes](https://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html). Look for Theme Browser link in the bottom left.